# VB.Net: how to save and handle large tables from different forms and keep them there when close and reopen the form.

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagrid

I have been trying to find an answer to this on the internet but with no success so far.

On a winform application I am working on, I have a principal form where users can fill a large datagrid (up to 1000 X 18) by either manually inserting value by value or pasting from an excel table (I already wrote the code for this). Also there are a few other forms where users can input other data through additional datagrids or textboxes. The Idea is to get the user to open each form, fill the data, and then close it and go to fill the next form. Input data will be a combination of boolean, double and strings.  Then there is on the principal form a "CALCULATE" button which performs operations on data coming from all the previous forms and displays the results in a "OUTPUT" form with a datagrid and a panel (through graphics). My question are:

1. What is the best way to save data from each form so that if the users close and then reopen that form, the data inserted previously are displayed and ready to be modified,deleted etc. I considered writing and reading from a .txt or XML, using databases,.CSV, my.settings(), etc, but I would like to ask what would be the best way to do it.
2. How to write code that performs math operations using data that have been inserted on different forms, after these forms have been filled and then closed
3. How to save all data so that I close and then launch the application again, all data are still there.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you use a datatable for the data (and you mean DataGridView for DataGrid), then you can save and load the table (data) from XML pretty easily.

Comment: Separate your View (Form) from your Model (Data Access, Logic) like in [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Thanks!!! 
If I want to use the write/read XML solution suggested by Plutonix should I save a different XML file for each datagridview and then read the XML at each form load?